# Can I use mongoose to give admin users access

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a back end UI for admin users. My client front end UI communicates with my Nodejs Express Mongodb database using Mongoose. But I am not sure if it will be safe or appropriate to give my admin users with different roles access to the database via the same Mongoose, or if I should create a completely independent Mongodb instance and then use db.createUser or something like that. Please can someone advise me on this? Thanks.